# RabbitMq with Vue JS

Tags: vue.js, rabbitmq, amqp, quasar-framework, quasar

I try to consume messages from frontend using rabbitMq, I already have rabbitMq and queue with data (AMQP). I searched for rabbitMq for Vue-Js or JavaScript but I didn't find any useful information.

so How I can consume from the rabbitMq using javaScript/vue-Js

Thanks.

Comment: When you say consume from frontend=> Do you mean show outputs of a RabbitMQ on the frontend as the arrive? or Do you want to use VueJS to post items to a RabbitMQ? Either way you need a transport mechanism bot from/to the RabbitMQ. I use web sockets for real-time data and normal HTTP Request for not-so realtime data. This way data can be retrieved or send to the endpoint(API or WS) that has RabbitMQ connected to it.

Comment: I want to show data from rabbitMQ to front end, yes I also use ws, but before I use ws MQTT and always just make an automatic queue, I'm confused about how to set the queue that I want to consume, is there a solution?

Comment: Have a look at this => https://medium.com/better-programming/implementing-rabbitmq-with-node-js-93e15a44a9cc

Comment: I have finished the back end, but I'm confused about how to display it to the front end, how come, I looked for examples I did not find for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you are still looking for a solution.
But i've done something similar a while ago.
Where i had a Vue3 frontend communicating with a spring-boot websocket.

I've just pushed my full code  into [Github repo named vue-springboot-websocket](https://github.com/abhinavganguly1987/vue-springboot-websocket/tree/main/websocket-vue-fe) for you in case it helps.
Basically this is what iv'e done in it:

1. I've built a spring boot websocket app following it's [getting started tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/), while this tutorial did provide a working frontend within it. I needed to do POC of a communication with a vue SPA.
2. So i had built a Vue3 app, a simple one with one component, within it i did exactly what Spring boot's getting started tutorial's frontend did:

> - Connect to a websocket
> - Subscribe to a topic
> - Send some message to the websocket server
> - Update on the UI the incoming messages on the topic

3. In the Vue app, i've used [sockjs-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sockjs-client) and [webstomp-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webstomp-client) to connect to a Spring-boot websocket server, the url for the server is set in [websocketutil.js](https://github.com/abhinavganguly1987/vue-springboot-websocket/blob/main/websocket-vue-fe/src/websocketutil.js#L13)

```
import SockJS from "sockjs-client";
import Stomp from "webstomp-client";
import store from "./store";

let stompClient = null;
let connected = false;

export function setConnected(connectedStatus) {
  connected = connectedStatus;
}

export function connect() {
  var socket = new SockJS("http://localhost:9090/totobhuto-sb-websocket-pro");
  stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
  stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
    setConnected(true);
    console.log(connected + " >>> TOTO Connected to FRAME : " + frame);
    stompClient.subscribe("/topic/greetings", function (greeting) {
      let tempMessage = JSON.parse(greeting.body).content;
      store.commit("addGreetingMessage", tempMessage);
    });
  });
}

export function disconnect() {
  if (stompClient !== null) {
    stompClient.disconnect();
    store.commit("clearAllGreetings");
  }
  setConnected(false);
  console.log(">>> Disconnected");
}

export function sendName(nameTxt) {
  console.log("+++++ then greeting to send " + nameTxt);
  stompClient.send("/app/hello", JSON.stringify({ name: nameTxt }), {});
}
```

4. I've maintained the updated received from the subscribed topic **/topic/greetings** into vuex state.

This state is what i am listening to for changes in the component [Websock.vue](https://github.com/abhinavganguly1987/vue-springboot-websocket/blob/main/websocket-vue-fe/src/components/Websock.vue)

```
<script>
import { connect, disconnect, sendName } from "@/websocketutil.js";
import { mapState } from "vuex";
export default {
  name: "Websock",
  data() {
    return {
      disabled: true,
      elname: "",
      allGreetings: [],
    };
  },
  props: {
    msg: String,
  },
  computed: mapState(["greetingMessages"]),
  methods: {
    connectWs() {
      this.disabled = false;
      connect();
    },
    disconnectWs() {
      this.disabled = true;
      disconnect();
    },
    sendGreetingName() {
      console.log(this.elname);
      sendName(this.elname);
      this.elname = "";
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to create a back-end server for your front-end Vue js app / React js / Android app ...etc , below is a simple graph that explains how you can consume your RabbitMQ messages using `NodeSrv` (a node js web server) , notice that you will need 2 queues , `Qa` for write , and `Qb` for read , whenever you send a ws request, your `NodeSrv` will send data to the queue `Qa` (I did not explain how data is sent to `Qb` , I assume there will be some other consumers that will consume `Qa` and send their result to `Qb`) and then `Qb` will be consumed by `NodeSrv` again and sent back to front end via websocket.

> Note1 : when Qb will be consumed by many consumers (NodeSrv) , RabbitMQ
> will balance the load to those consumers using Round Robin algorithm (
> message is forwarded to each consumer in turn )

> Note2 : since you can have many consumers , it would be nice to add a
> load balancer like haproxy or simply pm2 as a load balancer for the
> client side

[image: rabbitMQ with front end vuejs / React ...etc]